# no visible @interface for 'UITouch' declares the selector 'locationInView'

Tags: ios, xcode, uitouch, cgpoint

My app was working fine and today I started getting these random errors that read

`no visible @interface for 'UITouch' declares the selector 'locationInView'`

which I don't get because it was working perfectly fine before today and just started doing this today my code is:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

I have everything imported that I need to & I even checked in the UITouch class and it did have the "locationInView" method declared their so I don't know why this is happening I would appreciate any help I can get, please & thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
```

with

```
- (void)touchBegan:(CCTouch *)touch withEvent:(CCTouchEvent *)event {
```

for more info.
http://www.spritebuilder.com/update

Comment: what is the need of using third party api here